# Question about the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\sqrt{2+\arctan(1/x)}}$

Tags: limits

How does one evaluate the limit:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\sqrt{2+\arctan(1/x)}}$$

Comment: Notice the limit of $\arctan(1/x)$ when $x\rightarrow 0$ does not exist. Do you mean $x\rightarrow 0^+$ or $x\rightarrow 0^-$?

Comment: Assuming, though, that what's meant is a limit from above, you can evaluate the limit of the square root by taking the square root of the limit of the stuff under the radical (if that limit exists and is nonnegative). (Can you cite a theorem that tells you this is OK?) So that slightly simplifies things. How would you evaluate that interior limit?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

this is the graph of $\arctan x$ then, if you take $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \arctan (1/x)=\pi/2$
and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \arctan (1/x)=-\pi/2$. Therefore the limite   $\lim_{x\to 0} \arctan (1/x)\;\;\; \nexists$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\sqrt{2+\arctan \frac{1}{x}}=\sqrt{2+\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{2+\arctan \frac{1}{x}}=\sqrt{2-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

The limit does not exist at $0$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Hint

Here is a plot. math_man is obviously correct. But you could calculate the two limits as $x\to0^+$ and $x\to0^-$

[Plotted with Mathematica, the code is slightly truncated at the right]